# Saving an object via getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(item)

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hsqldb, spring-transactions

Even if the operation seems to be extremely frequently used I haven't found where is the problem in my code.
In DAO class I have:

```
    public class ItemDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ItemDao {
    @Transactional
    public void addItem(Item item){
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(item);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Item> findAllItem(){
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Item").list();
    }}
```

findAllItem() works well, whereas addItem() doesn't. When I click a button that invokes addItem() the following error is thrown:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.z.item.model.Item cannot be cast to java.util.Map
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.z.item.model.Item cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
.
.
.

But I haven't specified any Map as I use the object "Item" everywhere. Item object that is passed to addItem() is also correct. Why is this exception thrown?

Here is how I configure it:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="com.z.item.model.Item"
        table="item">

        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="ITEMNAME" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="amount" type="int">
            <column name="AMOUNT" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="price" type="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <column name="PRICE" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="itemDao"
         class="com.z.item.dao.impl.ItemDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>



   <bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
          <value>com/z/item/hibernate/Item.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? or should I just fix all these problems shown..

Answer (score 0):

For the `@Transactional` annotation you need to specify your write (save and delete) DAO methods with `false` and your read (get and load) methods with `true`.

The `@Transactional` is simply adding certain meta data for the method or class about whether the transaction is read only or write or whether it requires a new transaction etc.. for more information on the @Transactional annotation please read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings).

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void addItem(Item item){
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(item);
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Item> findAllItem(){
    return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Item").list();
}
```

Also, you should change your mapping to use `<class name="Item" table="item">` instead of `<class entity-name="com.z.item.model.Item" table="item">`. This mapping allows you to access the data as a dom4j tree, or as a graph of property name/value pairs or java Maps.  Specifying only an XML mapping without any associated class. The property names are purely logical constructs that can be referred to in HQL queries. See [the hibernate doco](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) for more info.

> **entity-name** (optional - defaults to the class name): Hibernate3 allows
>   a class to be mapped multiple times, potentially to different tables.
>   It also allows entity mappings that are represented by Maps or XML at
>   the Java level. In these cases, you should provide an explicit
>   arbitrary name for the entity. See Section 4.4, “Dynamic models” and
>   Chapter 18, XML Mapping for more information.

Comment: I've followed your ideas: first I added @Transactional(readOnly = false) for addItem(). But the ClassCastException was still thrown. Then I tried your another idea and removed this annotation over addItem() but then I got another error, this time: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect a change in the mapping that you should try. This should deal with the case problem. Sorry I missed that. I am also assuming that this is a simple object relation here? you don't want  any special mappings? For the 'bound to thread' issue. This is separate and has to do with how you are creating your hibernate session. see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d5e737

Comment: I think we are going in a right direction. In the tutorial I looked at, it was name but I changed it to entity-name. I changed that because it was fixing another error: SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/beans/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]...

Comment: Perfect. Now you just need to work these other things out and look at your session transaction management. For that above exception look at how you are injecting your session and how you have it defined.

Comment: What you have is a series of bugs or different questions. Maybe try keeping one question or related questions to a single thread. And open another question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue caused with  Hibernate. The issue may already have happened when you click the button and BEFORE reaching `addItem()`. Most likely, it is data mapping issue(I assume you map some data to Item first when clicking the button). Try to print out item before you call `addItem()`, you should see above exception even not calling `addItem()`.

Comment: True, I'm not sure if it's a Hibernate issue. But if the mapping is done wrong then my findAllItem() shouldn't work? and when I click on add button, I can already see a list of items correctly selected from the DB by findAllItem(). I've checked on debuger that the item that is passed to addItem() is correct. I've even made an experiment and created a completely new object of Item right in the addItem() and tried to save it, but the ClassCastException was still there.

Comment: You got result from findAllItem(), that means your item entity mapping is correct. From your log `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException`, you can see the issue happens when you try mapping data from UI to Item, not even reach `addItem()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there were a couple of things I did to make this code working.

1. I've changed my dao method to:

   @Transactional(readOnly=false)
   public void addItem(Item item){}
2. I've modified cglib version in pom.xml from 2.2. to 2.1.
3. I've changed the configuration to:

   ```
   <class name="pl.outbox.item.model.Item" table="item">
   <id name="id" type="int">
       <column name="ID" />
       <generator class="increment"/>
   </id>
   ```